# Cast As Time Remove Trailing Zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime field in Mssql. I am attempting to cast this to just time, but the result ends up with seven trailing zeros. I would like to just have the time, without the extraneous zeros. Here is my query with the result set.

```
SELECT cast(begin_time as time) AS begin_time FROM mytable;
```

Here is the result set:

```
08:08:31.0000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to a string with the `hh:mm:ss` style: `convert(varchar(8), begin_time, 108)` or `cast as time(0)` to round with the fraction seconds.